# Lock screen doesn't lock (plain Ubuntu & gnome-screensaver)

Tags: xfce, lock-screen, screensaver, gnome-screensaver, xfce4-power-manager

I have checked the following instructions, but none of them helps me (and I don't have sufficient reputation to comment on them):

- Xubuntu doesn't lock screen anymore
- Keyboard shortcut for Lockscreen not working

Situation is:

- If I press Ctrl-Alt-L or Windows-L the screensaver gets enabled but it doesn't lock the screen.
- Earlier I used Logout command which has locking command as a side feature, but the locking options seems to have been removed.
- If I go to All Settings --> Brightness & Lock, the Lock is grayed out but the option Require my password when waking from suspend is on. So I guess that is only from suspend and doesn't change screensaver settings.
- If I give command gnome-screensaver, it says that there is one running already.
- I gave command sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xfce4-session, and if I type xflock4 it now uses xscreensaver instead gnome-screensaver and follows its settings and locks the screen. But naturally I don't want to type this command every time I wish to lock the screen.
- I installed xfce4-power-manager and executed xfce4-power-manager-settings, but how do I enable it (xfce4-power-manager and xfce4-power-manager --restart didn't do it)?
- I have been unable to do any custom shortcuts: they all become disabled and I am unable to enable them.
- I haven't tried if rebooting would enable one of the several trials I have done.

Comment: Did you change the login manager recently? If so, changing it back will do the job. Else, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

I believe this fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade ubuntu-core-launcher
```

For some reason the core launcher didn't upgrade with everything else and was somehow out of sync with the rest of the OS.